# "PyObjC requires macOS to build" on Heroku while trying to deploy reddit bot

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

```
   Collecting pyobjc-core==6.2.2
     Downloading pyobjc-core-6.2.2.tar.gz (780 kB)
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z343rm35/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z343rm35/pyobjc-core/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-59wv4z7y
            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z343rm35/pyobjc-core/
       Complete output (2 lines):
       running egg_info
       error: PyObjC requires macOS to build
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

How can I fix this?

Comment: what packages are you using? What's in your requirements-file?

`pyobjc-core` is a package that will only run on Mac OS, 

but I doubt that any reddit bot package runs on objective C

Comment: Why are you trying to use this package on Heroku? A common cause of this is not using a virtualenv in development, not using a dependency manager during development, and then dumping _all_ of your Python packages to a `requirements.txt` at the end, just for Heroku. Does that sound familiar?

Comment: @DenisCornehl, Chris. Thank you for the replies. I wasn't using a virtual environment. Fixed the issue now.